# Convert Image Pixel Data to Coordinate Array

Tags: javascript, html, loops, canvas

I have the following code that draws an image to a canvas and gets the pixel data:

```
   var canvas=$('#canvas'),
       ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var data=ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

This pulls `RGBA` values which I need to store into an array that I'll be able to access using X/Y coordinates. The image drawn to the canvas is a black/white image - so it would check whether a pixel is black or white at `X`,`Y` - like:

```
imageArray[x][y]
```

I can't figure out how to loop the pixel data and save it to a `2d` array so I'd be able to call it by coordinates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is loop through the entire image data array and extract the values you need:

Each pixel takes up four spaces in the array for its rgba values, so we can loop through the total number of pixels and grab four values from the array each time.

You can get the y value (or row the pixel is on) by dividing the current index by the height and the x (or column pixel is on) by using the y value to subtract the rows from the current index, leaving the x.

```
var pixels = imageData.data;
var w = imageData.width;
var h = imageData.height;

var l = w * h;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    // get color of pixel
    var r = pixels[i*4]; // Red
    var g = pixels[i*4+1]; // Green
    var b = pixels[i*4+2]; // Blue
    var a = pixels[i*4+3]; // Alpha

    // get the position of pixel
    var y = parseInt(i / w, 10);
    var x = i - y * w;
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to reverse this proccess? (ie find the pixel's color "r" position within the `imageData.data` array)?

Comment: Sure. You can either call `ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1)` to return the rgba for the pixel at xy or do something like `var i = y * w + x * 4` (I think that's right!)

Comment: Yes I believe that that is correct (I ended up creating this: `function getpixel(x,y){
 var width = canvas.width;
 var id = x+(y*width);
 return pixels[id];
}` bearing in mind that I created a pixel array - with each pixel containing the 4 colour channels RGBA) - Thanks anyways :-)

Answer (score 6):

`ctx.getImageData` returns an object that contains a `.data` property.

That data property is an array that already contains all the pixel colors that you're looking for.

```
// get the imageData object
var imageData=ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// get the pixel color data array
var data=imageData.data;
```

The `data` array is a long array containing the red, green, blue & alpha (opacity) values for each pixel on the canvas.  The `data` array is shaped like this:

```
// top left pixel [0,0]
data[0]: Red value for pixel [0,0],
data[1]: Green value for pixel [0,0],
data[2]: Blue value for pixel [0,0],
data[3]: Alpha value for pixel [0,0],

// next pixel rightward [1,0]
data[4]: Red value for pixel [1,0],
data[5]: Green value for pixel [1,0],
data[6]: Blue value for pixel [1,0],
data[7]: Alpha value for pixel [1,0],

// and so on for each pixel on the canvas
...
```

You can get position of any [x,y] pixel within `data` like this:

```
// the data[] array position for pixel [x,y]
var n = y * canvas.width + x;
```

And then you can fetch that pixel's red, green, blue & alpha values like this:

```
var red=data[n];
var green=data[n+1];
var blue=data[n+2];
var alpha=data[n+3];
```